# Windows phone button without the default space?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to minimize the default border of every side of a button?

Comment: no its not the border, its the thing arround the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

When you open your project in Blend. Right click the button, go to edit template, edit current. You'l find that every button has a grid and a container. Make the size of both equal then, you'l see the default border's size same as the buttons size.

The same template can be used for other buttons too.